# read a variable while multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I get two streams of data from an API, so there are 3 threads, main one, stream1 and stream2. Stream1 and Stream2 need to process this data and once they're done they store them on main_value1 and main_value2.

From main thread I need to read the last value at any given time (so if I need this value and it is still processing then I get the last processed/stored one), what would be the optimal way? from the code example here I need help in coding functions get_main_value1() and, of course, get_main_value2()

```
def stream1():
    while True:
         main_value1 = process()
def stream2():
    while True:
        main_value2 = process2()
def get_main_value1(): ?
def get main_value2(): ?
def main():
    threading.Thread(function=stream1,).start()
    threading.Thread(function=stream2).start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,10))
        A = get_main_value1()
        B = get_main_value2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to make them global:

```
STREAM1_LAST_VALUE = None
def stream1():
    global STREAM1_LAST_VALUE
    while True:
         main_value1 = process()
         STREAM1_LAST_VALUE = main_value1

STREAM2_LAST_VALUE = None
def stream2():
    global STREAM2_LAST_VALUE
    while True:
        main_value2 = process2()
        STREAM2_LAST_VALUE = main_value2

def get_main_value1():
    return STREAM1_LAST_VALUE

def get main_value2():
    return STREAM2_LAST_VALUE

def main():
    threading.Thread(function=stream1,).start()
    threading.Thread(function=stream2).start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,10))
        A = get_main_value1()
        B = get_main_value2()
```

Comment: perhaps it's a stupid question: what if I require this value while it's being set by the function? what would happen, or this is impossible to happen?

Comment: @FroidDymylja I'm not sure I understand. If you look at my code `process2()` returns a value which then overwrites `STREAM2_LAST_VALUE`. Therefore no intermediate state is possible. Also `process2()` always sees the last value as well, so it can safely use it. If you would do updates to `STREAM2_LAST_VALUE` object directly then inconsistency would be possible. The consistency of simple read and write is guaranteed in Python.

Comment: _"The consistency of simple read and write is guaranteed in Python"_? Could you provide a Link to read up this.

Comment: @stovfl https://docs.python.org/2/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe There's a list of atomic operations there (not sure if complete but sufficient for our case). Sorry for the late response, missed the comment.